# Get Value Split Value And Show It In Input From Using JS

Tags: javascript

I need to grab a value from a select then add those values and show total in input box. It works as long as I don't use a split but I need that split because I need 2 different values in the value. I know the error is in my split somehow but just can't figure it out. Any help would be great!

Like I say, the script works great if I take out the split and use only numbers in the value of the select but I need 2 different values in the select value and to split it and get the 2nd number from that split. Example 1-15 I need the 15 to add to the others.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-header">Select 4 Products</div>
        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;">
        <p style="font-size:18px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">BV Needed For Platinum Package: 75</p>
            <p style="font-size:20px; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Current BV:  <input type="text" name="bv" id="bv" value="0" readonly></p>
            <br />
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p1" onchange="updateDue()">
                        <option value="" >Please Select A Product</option>                                    
                        <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                        <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                        <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                        <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                        <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p2" onchange="updateDue()">
                        <option value="" >Please Select A Product</option>                                    
                        <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                        <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                        <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                        <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                        <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p3" onchange="updateDue()">
                        <option value="" >Please Select A Product</option>                                    
                        <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                        <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                        <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                        <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                        <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p4" onchange="updateDue()">
                        <option value="" >Please Select A Product</option>                                    
                        <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                        <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                        <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                        <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                        <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function updateDue() {
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p1").value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p2").value);
var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p3").value);
var val4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p4").value);

var realbv1 = val1.split('|');
var realbv2 = val2.split('|');
var realbv3 = val3.split('|');
var realbv4 = val4.split('|');

if (!realbv1[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val1 = realbv1[1]; }
if (!realbv2[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val2 = realbv2[1]; }
if (!realbv3[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val3 = realbv3[1]; }
if (!realbv4[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val4 = realbv4[1]; }

var ansD = document.getElementById("bv");
ansD.value = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
}
//]]></script>
```

Any help on this would be great. And the only reason I keep rambling on is because this form is making me add more details but I have added all the details. It keeps saying that my post is mostly code, that's crazy, how much more detail can I add to this to make it go away. So if you're still reading this I am sorry this is just to make that stupid error go away. They should really fix that because not all problems require a book of details in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this lines...:

```
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p1").value);
```

If the content is **"1|15"** the result will be 1 and so the second number has gone away.

Change that line to:

```
var val1 = document.getElementById("p1").value;
```

In order to get the sum you can simply add a plus sign in front of each addendum:

```
ansD.value = +val1 + +val2 + +val3 + +val4;
```

The snippet:

```js
function updateDue() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById("p1").value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById("p2").value;
    var val3 = document.getElementById("p3").value;
    var val4 = document.getElementById("p4").value;

    var realbv1 = val1.split('|');
    var realbv2 = val2.split('|');
    var realbv3 = val3.split('|');
    var realbv4 = val4.split('|');

    if (!realbv1[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val1 = realbv1[1]; }
    if (!realbv2[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val2 = realbv2[1]; }
    if (!realbv3[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val3 = realbv3[1]; }
    if (!realbv4[1]) { val1 = 0; } else { val4 = realbv4[1]; }

    var ansD = document.getElementById("bv");
    ansD.value = +val1 + +val2 + +val3 + +val4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-header">Select 4 Products</div>
            <div class="card-body" style="padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;">
                <p style="font-size:18px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">BV Needed For Platinum Package: 75</p>

                <p style="font-size:20px; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Current BV: <input
                        type="text" name="bv" id="bv" value="0" readonly></p>
                <br/>

                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-3 text-center">
                        <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p1" onchange="updateDue()">
                            <option value="">Please Select A Product</option>
                            <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                            <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                            <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                            <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                            <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                            <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 text-center">
                        <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p2" onchange="updateDue()">
                            <option value="">Please Select A Product</option>
                            <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                            <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                            <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                            <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                            <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                            <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 text-center">
                        <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p3" onchange="updateDue()">
                            <option value="">Please Select A Product</option>
                            <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                            <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                            <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                            <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                            <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                            <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 text-center">
                        <select name="product1" class="form-control" id="p4" onchange="updateDue()">
                            <option value="">Please Select A Product</option>
                            <option value="1|15">Product 1</option>
                            <option value="2|13">Product 2</option>
                            <option value="3|9">Product 3</option>
                            <option value="4|8">Product 4</option>
                            <option value="5|13">Product 5</option>
                            <option value="6|13">Product 6</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working :) Try it on your side.

```
function updateDue() {
var val1 = (document.getElementById("p1").value);
var val2 = (document.getElementById("p2").value);
var val3 = (document.getElementById("p3").value);
var val4 = (document.getElementById("p4").value);

var realbv1 = val1.split('|');
var realbv2 = val2.split('|');
var realbv3 = val3.split('|');
var realbv4 = val4.split('|');

val1 = (!realbv1[1] ? 0 : parseInt(realbv1[1]));
val2 = (!realbv1[2] ? 0 : parseInt(realbv1[2]));
val3 = (!realbv1[3] ? 0 : parseInt(realbv1[3]));
val4 = (!realbv1[4] ? 0 : parseInt(realbv1[4]));

var ansD = document.getElementById("bv");
ansD.value = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
}
```